# Настроить урл страниц (ЧПУ)

Tags: .htaccess, url

Доброго времени суток!

Есть сайт с несколькими папками со страницами и файлами index.php и .htaccess в корне.

Получилось убрать index.php с урла главной страницы.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R]
```

А как изменить урл, к примеру `mysite.com/users/userpage.php` на `mysite.com/userpage` ? В каждой папке со страницами создавать файл .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте вот это `RewriteRule ^userpage$ /user/user_page.php [L]`

Comment: Пробовал, не получается

Comment: @Хруст структура проекта  http://prntscr.com/ohclhf , http://prntscr.com/ohcloy .
Попробуйте обновить кеш в браузере, возможно файл .htaccess  закешировался. Все работает.